# How to replace share() function with singletone()

Tags: laravel, function, singleton, share

In Laravel 5.4 is the share-function no longer supported. It is recommended to use singleton(). So I tried several things.

This is the code I would like to replace with singleton()

```
$this->bind('Configuration',
   $this->share(function () use ($config) {
         return new Configuration($config);
   }), true
);
```

Any Solution to fix this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for response

I have used wrap()

```
$this->bind('Configuration',
            $this->wrap(function () use ($config) {
                return new Configuration($config);
            }), true
        );
```

And this works for me..
referred from here new method https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Container/Container.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->app->singleton('Configuration', function () use ($config) {
    return new Configuration($config);
});
```

If you have container instance then

```
$container->singleton('Configuration', function () use ($config) {
    return new Configuration($config);
});
```

You can read more about bindings here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#binding